# Local and remove branches have diverged after rebase on master and push -f

Tags: git

I have a dozen of commits in a local branch which I already pushed to remote one. Then I performed `git rebase master` + `git push -f` several times.

Thus, I was sure remote branch is completely replaced with local one.

But when I execute `git status`, I can see something like

```
On branch origin/fix/my-branch
Your branch and 'origin/fix/my-branch' have diverged,
and have 59 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

`$ git pull origin fix/my-branch`

```
From my-server.local:bbb/web
 * branch            fix/my-branch -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

and here is what git says when I'm trying to remove local branch after remote branch has been merged into `master`

```
warning: not deleting branch 'fix/my-branch' that is not yet merged to
     'refs/remotes/origin/fix/my-branch', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'fix/my-branch' is not fully merged.
```

git version 2.7.4, Linux

**UPDATE**

I've just realized, that first commit in that chain was made by me from another computer, and on that another computer there is a misspelling in git account email address. But that still doesn't explain what divergency there is between the branches because both have the same number of commits and identical commit hashes.

Comment: And what do you need ?

Comment: I need to have a clean repo state.

Comment: @gumkins "both have the same number of commits and identical commit hashes." That is not correct. That git status message means that `git log -1 HEAD` and `git log -1 origin/fix/my-branch` will show different commit hashes (ie. the head of the remote and local branches are different).

Comment: yes, that is what I would expect, but, I've just checked that with commands you have provided and they (those top commits) are exactly the same (hash, date, author, comment ...)

Comment: Have you tried doing `git push -f` again? What was the output when you did it in the first place?

Comment: Seems like you have an issue with the way your references are configured, and also what branch you're on (it is `origin/fix/my-branch`, not `fix/my-branch` as it should be). Having output of the following commands would help to diagnose: `git status`, `git log -1 HEAD`, `git log -1 fix/my-branch`, `git log -1 origin/fix/my-branch`, `git log -1 remotes/origin/fix/my-branch`, `cat .git/config`, `cat .git/HEAD`, `ls -l -R .git/refs/`, `cat .git/heads/fix/my-branch`, `cat .git/heads/origin/fix/my-branch`, `cat .git/remotes/origin/fix/my-branch`, `cat .git/remotes/origin/origin/fix/my-branch`.